# How do I describe the change adding "to be" makes to a verb

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I tutor student in SAT Reading.    One of the SAT tests has the following sentence:

"With their dark dungeons and damp living quarters, medieval castles offered few of the comforts to be found in royal palaces."

The student thought this must be wrong as "to be" seemed superfluous.  To me, there's a subtle difference in meaning if the sentence was changed to "few of the comforts found in royal palaces."  The only way I could describe it was that "to be" adds a more theoretical and abstract quality to the sentence.

Is there a clearer way to put all this and the change "to be" makes?

Thx in advance,  J

Comment: There is no difference in meaning; _To be_-Deletion is a common rule for infinitive clauses with predicate nouns or adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant question here, it seems to me, is What part of the complete idea can you omit without any loss of meaning?

The sentence

> With their dark dungeons and damp living quarters, medieval castles offered few of the comforts found in royal palaces.

can be read in at least two ways: as comparing medieval castles to medieval royal palaces, or as comparing medieval castles to modern royal palaces. In the first case, we can express the complete idea this way:

> With their dark dungeons and damp living quarters, medieval castles offered few of the comforts that were to be found in royal palaces.

And in the second, we can express it this way:

> With their dark dungeons and damp living quarters, medieval castles offered few of the comforts that are to be found in royal palaces.

Neither the four-words-shorter form

> With their dark dungeons and damp living quarters, medieval castles offered few of the comforts found in royal palaces.

nor the two-words-shorter form

> With their dark dungeons and damp living quarters, medieval castles offered few of the comforts to be found in royal palaces.

is incorrect structurally; but neither clarifies the era of royal palaces that the writer is comparing medieval castles to. In my view the loss in meaning occurs not at the step that John Lawler in his comment above calls *to be*-deletion (versus *to be*-retention), but at the step where the sentence loses the distinction in time frame that was (or might have been) supplied by the appropriate choice between "that were" or "that are."

On the other hand, maybe the author doesn't care which era of royal palaces the reader imagines the medieval castles are being contrasted with. In that case, the to-be and the not-to-be versions are equally noble in the mind, and "that were" versus "that are" is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit astonished about the tag subjunctive mood. I don't
see any subjunctive but an infinitive passive.

Infinitives active (normal forms): to see, to have seen

Infinitives passive (normal forms): to be seen, to have been seen.

1 comforts to be found in royal palaces

Here the infinitive passive stresses the idea of passive and possibility: comforts that can be found in royal palaces.

2 comforts found in royal places

Here the "found in royal palaces" is a normal shortened relative clause: comforts that are found in royal palaces.

It is true, the difference is subtle, nevertheless there is a slight shift in meaning. In 1 the idea is in many royal palaces such comforts can be found, but there may be some which don't have such comforts.

In 2 the statement is a general statement: Such comforts are found in royal palaces.